# Solve $3x \equiv 17 \pmod{2014}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Solve

$$3x \equiv 17 \pmod{2014}$$

So first I suppose $3^{-1} \pmod{2014}$

$2014 = 671(3) + 1 \implies 1 = 2014 - 671(3)$

But this gives $3^{-1} = 1 \pmod{2014}$

which is incorrect?

Comment: take a look at extended euclidian algorithm to compute multiplicative inverse

Comment: You have the multiplicative inverse the wrong way around... you need to look for $3x\equiv 1 \bmod 2014$ not $3x\equiv -1 \bmod 2014$

Comment: I dont get it. I was looking at $3x \equiv 1 \pmod{2014}$ ?

Comment: Your workings give $3^{-1}\equiv -671 \bmod 2014$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$3x=17\implies x=3^{-1}\cdot17 $$

Now, you can see at once that $\;2014=1\pmod 3\;$ , so

$$2\cdot2014+1=4029\implies 4029\div3=1343\implies 3^{-1}=1343\pmod{2014}$$

and thus

$$x=1343\cdot17\pmod{2014}=677\pmod{2014}$$

Comment: (+1) Sir! But why are you doing $2\cdot 2014 + 1$ ??

Comment: No but I got, $3^{-1} = 1 \pmod{2014}$? ???

Comment: Because since $\;2014=1\pmod 3\;$ , then $\;2\cdot2014=2\pmod 3\;$ , and then $\;2\cdot2014+1=0\pmod 3\;$

Comment: @Amad27 That is obviously wrong, right?! $\;x^{-1}=1\pmod m\iff x=1\pmod m\;$ , for any integer $\;m\;$ and coprime $\;x\;$ !

Comment: Wait, so  let me ask. What is $3^{-1} \pmod{2014}$ ?

Comment: @Amad27 $\;3^{-1}=t\pmod{2014}\iff 3t=1\pmod{2014}\;$ . As shown above, we get $\;3^{-1}=1343\pmod{2104}\;$ .

Comment: Here it is:

From Euclids, algorithm I get. 

$$2014 = 3(671) + 1$$ 

Then $\implies 1 = 2014 - 3(671)$

So $3^{-1} \pmod{2014} = -671$

Then 

$$3x \equiv 17 \pmod{2014}$$ 

$$x \equiv (17)(-671) \pmod{2014} \equiv -11407 \pmod{2014}$$


$$-11407 = 5(2014) - 1337 \equiv 677$$

Comment: @Amad27 Yes, that is correct . Observe that $\;1343=-671\pmod{2104}\;$  and thus we get the same !

Comment: Except the sign though. There must be something wrong there.

Comment: @Amad27 You've already asked quite a few question about modular arithmetic. I think you're lacking some basic understanding of this subject, and I think it'd be good for you to go the basics again before you attempt to go on anymore. In this case, we have that $\;-671\pmod{2014}\;$ **is exactly the same** as $\;1343\pmod{2014}\;$ , so I don't understand what you say about "except the sign"! The sign doesn't really matter here. We also have that $\;3=-3=-18=12\pmod 3\;$ , or $\;4=-3=11=-31\pmod 7\;$ , and etc.

Comment: I meant the answer is suppose to be $x \equiv 677$ not $-677$

Answer (score 1):

$3^{-1}=-671\bmod 2014$, so the solution is $x=-671\times 17\bmod 2014$. You should get  $677$ at the end.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ {\rm mod}\,\ 3n\!+\!1\!:\,\ 3(-n)\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 3^{-1}\equiv -n$

**Alternatively** $ $ note $\,\ \dfrac{1}{3} \,\equiv\, \dfrac{n}{3n}\,\equiv\, \dfrac{n}{-1}\equiv -n\ $ by [Gauss's algorithm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)

Answer (score 0):

$3x=2014~k+17=3~\underbrace{(671~k+6)}_x+\underbrace{(k-1)}_0\quad=>\quad k=1~$ and $~x=677$.